# How can i structure a MySQL database for a music track list?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mariadb

How would you go about structuring a MySQL database like this one: There can be many tracklists, tracklists will have many tracks and those tracks will have id, name and a timestamp.
Here is more info I would like to be stored in the database.

### Tracklist:

```
Tracklist Name
Tracklist id
Category
Tracks(songs)
```

### Track(song)

```
Track(song) id
Track(song) name
Timestamp
```

Any thoughts on how to design my database would be awesome.

Comment: [Déjà vu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934808/structuring-a-mysql-database-for-music-tracklist) anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make one master table for tracklist, lets say tracklist_master with your required columns and make another table for track mapping with tracklist ,let say tracklist_trake_mapping with tracklist_id in it.

So, your both table will look like:

```
1) tracklist_master:
    - tracklist_id (pk)
    - tracklist_name
    - category

2) tracklist_trake_mapping:
    - tracklist_trake_mapping_id
    - tracklist_id (fk to tracklist_master)
    - track_name
    - timestamp
```

You can easily get list of all track with tracklist name in single query.

Comment: he can't have one song in multiple playlists with this :).

Comment: Why? what will be the issue? @revengeance